# SharePoint 2013 document library folder limitation

Tags: folder, performance, limitations, row-limit

We are working on new project with required storing >50k documents in a document library under single folder. I am wondering if there is any limitation on how many documents we can store in a folder. Unfortunately, because of a project requirement, we cannot split these ~50k documents in multiple folders. Please note that we are **not** looking for maximum number of items a document library can store.

Any link or reference from Microsoft on this particular limitation is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per MSFT the limit of items in a Library (including folder) is 30M, that's mean if you have the 1 folder in your document library that can contain upto 30M items.

But real Catch is the List View Threshold, which is 5000 items per view( you can change it on prem). So if your library having more than 5K items then you have to filter the items in a way that a view can only return upto 5K items...if more than 5K items return then it will throw the error.

In your scenario with 50K items, i think you need multiple views.

You can read more over here.
https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?CorrelationId=7a736c02-6c96-4e29-a4b4-693b33187e97&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you Waqas. Is there any alternative, if we want to generate view/report/export which returns around 8k records based on particular filter or full text search?

Comment: Workaround is you can increase the List view threshold limit, but keep in mind, in that way you compromise on performance...But if you have enough meomry then you will fine...We have 50K list view threshold limit for one of web app.:)

Comment: Look like we also have to go with that route and increase threshold limit. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE : Is there any limitation in creating number of folders inside a folder or may at root doc library. I mean how many folders can be created inside a folder or in a root lib? My environment is Office365

Answer (score 0):

The answer directly from MS:

> Documents - 30,000,000 per library - Supported You can create very large
>   document libraries by nesting folders, or using standard views and
>   site hierarchy. This value may vary depending on how documents and
>   folders are organized, and by the type and size of documents stored.

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

The max capacity of files should be related with the quota of the web app

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft need to make this clearer. There are two scenarios for doc libs:

1. Archive (rarely used) - Place up to 30,000,000 items in a document library, but remember to create ListViews not exceeding 4,999. Filter by ID range possibly. Possibly use indexes and metadata to improve speed
2. Migrated File Share (used a lot by multiple users) - Break up into say 4,000 doc maximum category. Place no more than 4,999 items in each document library - no more. The "Lock Escalation" occurs on a table when more than 4,999 items are accessed on SQL Server. This blocks other users accessing the table and shows a message. SP 2016 has new large table search, up to 10,000 items using auto-indexing.