# How many folders we can create in single document library in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I want to know that how may folders we can create in document library in SharePoint 2013.

In [msdn article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) they said that 30,000,000 documents per document library, but what about folders per document library?

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2013 document library folder limitation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132265/sharepoint-2013-document-library-folder-limitation)

Comment: @ Dikesh Gandi.. that question is different one and not asked for specific folder limitation of document library. please take a look in that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create very large document libraries by nesting folders, or using standard views and site hierarchy. This value may vary depending on how documents and folders are organized, and by the type and size of documents stored.

But there is no such limitation on folder creation in SharePoint 2013 Document library. But yes, your document library can contains upto 30M **items(Documents+folders)**.

Comment: Hello Vishal, Did my answers helps you? If you need more information than kindly let me know.

Comment: Please close the question by posting the resolution if you found any apart from above answers. So others can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 2):

Documents and folders all are treated as items.
So the limit mentioned consist of all including folders as well.

To test it, write a query which will return total count. and another query where item is not folder. It should show the difference. Which in terms say folders are also treated as items.

PS: Folders also affects threshold limit.